# How to solve this type of integration?

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I had the following integration: $$\int_0^z w^{m-1}K_0(2\frac{m}{\Omega}\sqrt{w})dw.\tag{1}$$

Can i use the following formula from Table of integrals to solve the integral in eq. $(1)$

$$\int_0^{\infty}x^{\mu}K_v(ax)dx=2^{\mu-1}a^{-\mu-1}\Gamma\left(\frac{1+\mu+v}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1+\mu-v}{2}\right).$$
Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: No, you can't. The first integral is basically *indefinite*.

Comment: Ok. Could you please tell the approach to solve this integration.

Answer (score 0):

It is much more complicated for finite values of $z$ since it will be (assuming $m>0$).

Let $w=\frac{ \Omega ^2}{4 m^2}t^2$ to face
$$I=2 \left(\frac{\Omega ^2}{4m^2}\right)^m\int  t^{2 m-1} K_0(t)\,dt$$
$$\int  t^{2 m-1} K_0(t)\,dt=$$ $$\frac{t^{2 m} \left(2 m K_0(t) \, _1F_2\left(1;m,m+1;\frac{t^2}{4}\right)+t K_1(t)
   \, _1F_2\left(1;m+1,m+1;\frac{t^2}{4}\right)\right)}{4 m^2}$$

For $t=0$ the value is zero.

Comment: Can you please tell me the procedure to solve this type of integration.